# Is there any way to get the URLs of media files (all representations) from a DASH manifest in dash.js player?

Tags: mpeg-dash, dash.js

I'm just starting with [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js) and I would like to parse a manifest/ play list (`.mpd`) in order to get the URLs where the mediafiles of each *Representation* are located. i.e.,

```
<Representation 1>
   BaseUrl/representation1-1.mp4
   BaseUrl/representation1-2.mp4
   BaseUrl/representation1-3.mp4
   .....
<Representation n>
   BaseUrl/representationN-1.mp4
   BaseUrl/representationN-2.mp4
   BaseUrl/representationN-3.mp4
   .....
```

The manifest could define either a VoD/ or Live services, and it could use templates(number/time based) or not.

I had started by looking a manifest parser in the dash API but I didnt get luck.  I dont need to play the streams, just to get the URLs of each segment. Actually, what I have done to now is exactly what I dont want: to play all the "representation" in the player and then get the URLs by using DashMetrics module.

Once I had that info, I would download those media files in order to analyze the QoE of each *Representation* in offline mode.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!!!